# Window key does not bring up start menu and middle mouse button doesn't bring up scrolling

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-11, mouse

Subsequent to a driver update from Dell's OEM SupportAssist software, my Window key no longer brings up the Windows menu and the middle mouse button doesn't bring up scrolling. The Window key is working because when I tried using `Win + L`, the computer locks. I suspect this is a problem with the driver, and it's probably a bug by the driver supplier. Dell wanted to charge me $99 plus tax for this issue. I think this is their mistake for creating the bug, they should take care of it. But they wouldn't. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Thank you for your input.

Comment: You can roll back the driver that was replaced. Also, try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: General FYI: Windows update will auto install drivers for hardware it detects _(SupportAssist isn't necessary)_ and is what's recommended to use since OEMs will stop supporting systems when they're EOL. The only OEM drivers that should _always_ be used are the CPU chipset drivers, any other CPU drivers _(such as thermal)_, GPU drivers for the GPU the system shipped with _(OEMs almost always customize the generic GPU drivers provided by the GPU OEM, and GPU OEM installers will often refuse installation in this scenario)_, as well as any custom OEM software like Alienware Audio, AlienFX, etc.

Comment: As @harrymc said roll back driver. Device Manager, double-click keyboard for properties window, Driver tab for rollback, Events tab will show driver install dates. Maybe you can find the setting in registry? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398476/location-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-registry

Comment: @harrymc, gregg Thank you for your input. Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. I don't know what driver should be rolled back. Should it be the BIOS driver? Thanks

Comment: The BIOS/UEFI doesn't have a driver and Windows Update won't touch it, although SupportAssist can update it. Look in the updates history for Windows Update and SupportAssist (if it has one) to try to guess what it was. If System Restore is activated, you may rollback all of Windows to a previous date, to check if an update was really the problem.

Comment: @harrymc I suspect it's Intel management engine interface driver, yet the rollback button is grayed out...

Comment: What version is this driver? Perhaps an earlier version can be found.

Comment: You will find the latest version [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/34227/software/chipset-software/intel-management-engine.html)

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows 11,  get the Windows 11 ISO (Media Creation Link) and download to a USB key.

Start with the USB Key and run Setup on the key.

This should launch the ability to do a Repair Install.

Assuming it launches Repair, try Keep Everything and see if that corrects the issue.

If not, try Keep just Data and then you will need to install your software.

Also, if the computer will at least start, you can also use Windows Reset in Start, System, Windows Update.

The last step would be to back up everything and install Windows fresh.

Comment: my mistake. I'm on a windows 11 machine

Comment: Given your first error, I have changed this to run a Repair Install to fix the issue.

Comment: I've tried in-place upgrade with an Win 11 ISO, but it still didn't fix the problem...

Comment: In that case you will need to reinstall Windows fresh.   Answer amended

Comment: I suspect it's an issue with a driver. The outcome would be the same after I reinstall windows